# What is an efficient way to search through an array of recipes and match multiple words on some ingredients list

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dart

```js
var mockRecipes = [{
  "name": "PUMPKIN PEANUT BUTTER CHICKEN SOUP",
  "ingredientsByCategory": [{
      "category": "ingredients",
      "ingredients": [
        "1 (15 ounce) can light coconut milk",
        "1 (15 ounce) can pumpkin puree",
        "1 ½ cups low-sodium chicken broth",
        "½ cup natural creamy peanut butter (just peanuts + salt as the ingredients)"
        "1 tablespoon freshly grated ginger",
        "3 cloves garlic, minced",
        "½ teaspoon cayenne (use only ¼ teaspoon if you don’t like things as spicy)",
        "½ teaspoon salt",
        "Freshly ground black pepper",
        "1 ½ pounds boneless skinless chicken breast",
        "1 yellow onion, diced"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "for serving",
      "ingredients": [
        "Fresh chopped cilantro",
        "Roasted chopped peanuts",
        "Cooked brown rice"
      ]
    }
  ],
}];
```

Given the structure above, I would like to have a search input to search recipes by name or by ingredients(whatever is in the ingredients lists). The following searching should either return this recipe or not;

```
Input: pum pe but chi -> returns true because it matches the name
Input: pum pe buts chi -> returns false
Input: coco puree butter cilant -> returns true
Input: cilantro beans -> returns false
Input: co be rice cilant roast yellow 1 -> returns true
```

Just looking for a general direction on what is the best way to implement this without brute force. All in the frontend

Comment: What have you tried in terms of code to achieve this? Please post your attempt/s...

Comment: for example having this work for searching recipe names, i have this code `void onSearch(query) {
    var queryArray = query.split(" ");

    searchedRecipes = allRecipes
        .where((recipe) => queryArray.every((element) =>
            recipe.name.contains(new RegExp(element, caseSensitive: false))))
        .toList();
  
  }`

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways than brute force. You should manage a data structure to help you with this task. Notice that you should do a pre-processing of the receipts list and use some memory for that.

The best way I can think of, in terms of efficiency, is to create a graph of chars. Iterate the ingredients/name strings, and in each iteration keep building your graph object:

For each word `w`, iterate the word's chars. Add `w[0]` to the root of the graph object -

```
if (!graph[w[0]]) graph[w[0]] = {};
```

Keep iterating the chars of that word, and fill the graph nestedly:

```
if (!graph[w[0]][w[1]]...[w[w.length-1]]) graph[w[0]][w[1]]...[w[w.length-1]] = {};
```

Do the same for every word in the ingredients. Notice that in the next iterations, you might conflict with previous chars, and thats totally fine. In terms of time complexity, for `n` words (while every word has `O(1)` length), building the graph takes `O(n)` and is being done just once as long as the receipts doesn't change.

Example:

Say this is your receipt:
`'ingredients': ['pumpkin', 'puree']`

Then your graph will look like:

```
{
  p: {
    u: {
      m: { p: { k: { i: { n: {} } } } },
      r: { e: { e: {} } }
    },
  }
}
```

After having the initial overhead of building this graph, scanning it would be extremely easy and efficient - for each input word, let's say `pum`, traverse the graph char by char. If you can't find your next step - the word isn't included.

`return (graph.p && graph.p.u && graph.p.u.m)`

For input of `m` words (of length `O(1)` each), getting a boolean answer would take `O(m)` time, which is the minimum time that you may achieve.

Of course the whole process of both building the graph and scanning it later should be automated, and my examples shown above shouldn't be written manually, as I just used it for demonstration.